# JFormattedTextField currency formatter enters two 0 after inserting number

Tags: java, swing, currency, formatter, jformattedtextfield

In this GIF, you can see what is wrong:

[image: Gif of what's wrong]

The code for this JFormattedTextField and the JFormatter looks like this:

```
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
    formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
    formatter.setOverwriteMode(true);
    JFormattedTextField price = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
    price.setValue(0.00);
```

Every time a number hits the separator, it adds two additional zeros.
How can I prevent that?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your code fragment, but you should define the JFormattedTextField one time when you create the GUI.  If you post a [mre] that a person can copy, paste in his Eclipse and run, then you might get some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the decimal separator. When the contained text is `1,00 €`, corresponding to `1.0`, and you overwrite the `,` with `1`, the resulting text first is `1100 €` which will be parsed to `1100.0` as the `NumberFormat` is tolerant regarding absent or misplaced grouping separators, as well as absent fractional parts. The number `1100.0` is then reformatted to `1.100,00 €`.

This repeats when you continue typing.

The fact that the comma gets overwritten seems to be a bug. I found the following code in the `NumberFormatter`:

```
/**
 * Subclassed to treat the decimal separator, grouping separator,
 * exponent symbol, percent, permille, currency and sign as literals.
 */
boolean isLiteral(Map<?, ?> attrs) {
    if (!super.isLiteral(attrs)) {
        if (attrs == null) {
            return false;
        }
        int size = attrs.size();

        if (attrs.get(NumberFormat.Field.GROUPING_SEPARATOR) != null) {
            size--;
            if (attrs.get(NumberFormat.Field.INTEGER) != null) {
                size--;
            }
        }
        if (attrs.get(NumberFormat.Field.EXPONENT_SYMBOL) != null) {
            size--;
        }
        if (attrs.get(NumberFormat.Field.PERCENT) != null) {
            size--;
        }
        if (attrs.get(NumberFormat.Field.PERMILLE) != null) {
            size--;
        }
        if (attrs.get(NumberFormat.Field.CURRENCY) != null) {
            size--;
        }
        if (attrs.get(NumberFormat.Field.SIGN) != null) {
            size--;
        }
        return size == 0;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Contrary to the documentation comment’s enumeration, which mentions “decimal separator”, the field `NumberFormat.Field.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR` is not handled within the method.

Since this is a package-private method, as most of the implementation, there is no way to alter this behavior from an application. We can place a work-around at the incoming `NumberFormat` side, by creating a custom `NumberFormat` which removes the marker for the `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR` at the character iterator already.

First, we add a helper method

```
/**
 * Converts DECIMAL_SEPARATOR fields to literal text.
 */
static AttributedCharacterIterator
    convertSeparatorFieldToLiteral(AttributedCharacterIterator aci) {

    if(aci.current() == CharacterIterator.DONE) return aci;
    int o = aci.getBeginIndex();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(aci.getEndIndex()-o);
    do sb.append(aci.current()); while(aci.next() != CharacterIterator.DONE);
    AttributedString s = new AttributedString(sb.toString());
    for(aci.first(); aci.current() != AttributedCharacterIterator.DONE;
        aci.setIndex(aci.getRunLimit())) {

        Map<AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute, Object> attr = aci.getAttributes();
        if(attr == null || attr.isEmpty()) continue;
        if(attr.containsKey(NumberFormat.Field.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR)) {
            if(attr.size() == 1) continue;
            attr = new HashMap<>(attr);
            attr.remove(NumberFormat.Field.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR);
        }
        s.addAttributes(attr, aci.getRunStart()-o, aci.getRunLimit()-o);
    }
    return s.getIterator();
}
```

Then, change the example usage to

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
NumberFormat myFormat = new NumberFormat() {
    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(double number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition p) {
        return format.format(number, toAppendTo, p);
    }
    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(long number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
        return format.format(number, toAppendTo, pos);
    }
    @Override
    public Number parse(String source, ParsePosition parsePosition) {
        return format.parse(source, parsePosition);
    }
    @Override
    public AttributedCharacterIterator formatToCharacterIterator(Object obj) {
        AttributedCharacterIterator aci = format.formatToCharacterIterator(obj);
        return convertSeparatorFieldToLiteral(aci);
    }
};

NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(myFormat);

formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
formatter.setOverwriteMode(true);
JFormattedTextField price = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
price.setValue(0.00);
```

The custom `NumberFormat` delegates to the original format in almost every regard. The only difference is that the `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR` attribute gets removed from the character iterator, so the decimal separator will be treated like literal text of the format which can not be changed.

As a result, you can type straight-forwardly in overwrite mode. However, the handling of a `JFormattedTextField` in overwrite mode still is tricky. You need to `setMinimumIntegerDigits(…)` to make writing numbers with more digits easier, but deleting decimal digits will become unintuitive then.